# Google apps for buisness redirect to Amazon S3

Tags: redirects, amazon-s3

I want to make a domain on [Google Apps For Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) with a single page on [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) on the same domain Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound very difficult when you think about it, but it could be.

Thinking about it, you'd have to speak to your domain manager to ask if a URL can be shared between 2 hosts at the same time. This is probably likely, but it will require some work. After confirming if double hosting is possible (which I think is very very possible), the rest will become quite easy, as you will just need to have all your links point to that URL and it will pull the data from AWS.